# Python 3: iGraph from Data Frame verticies missing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, igraph

I am having some trouble importing some data via a pandas data frame and using it in iGraph. I first tried using my data but as it did not work, I created a smaller data set which reproduced the issue. I made the test data in excel and then used pandas.read_clipboard (running line by line) to analyze.

As for the setup I am running, I am using Spyder 4.1.5, Python 3.8, iGraph 0.8.3, and Pandas 1.1.3.

The data is seen in the following two blocks.

Vertices file:

```
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
```

Edges file:

```
1    2    0.15
1    3    0.15
2    3    0.3
2    4    0.45
3    4    0.15
```

And then the python code looks like this

```
from igraph import Graph
from pandas import read_table, read_clipboard
from cairo import *

#copy data from vertices file and run line once
test_nodes = read_clipboard(header = None, names = ["NodeID" , "Attribute"])

#copy data from edges file and run line once
test_edges = read_clipboard(header = None, names = ["From", "To", "Length"])    


G2 = Graph.DataFrame(edges = test_edges, directed = False, vertices = test_nodes)
```

This results in the following error

```
[Folder location]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py:576: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  mask &= (ar1 != a)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-95-1b701f504cfc>", line 1, in <module>
    G2 = Graph.DataFrame(edges = test_edges, directed = False, vertices = test_nodes)

  File "[Folder Location]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\igraph\__init__.py", line 3124, in DataFrame
    raise ValueError(

ValueError: Some vertices in the edge DataFrame are missing from vertices DataFrame
```

If I try again using .astype(Float), it no longer has the line including the FutureWarning, but the ValueError remains, which leads me to believe it is something to do with iGraph's ability to read the data frame correctly.

When I try to run it using edges alone, it runs just fine and I am able to plot as seen here:
[image]

However, I need the vertex attributes in order to calculate PC of the network I am analyzing.

Thank you in advance for any help that you can provide!

EDIT: So I noticed when looking into the iGraph code, that the following is used to compare vertices with edges

```
    names_vertices = vertices.iloc[:, 0].astype(str)
    names_edges = np.unique(edges.values[:, :2])
    if len(np.setdiff1d(names_edges, names_vertices)):
                raise ValueError(
                    'Some vertices in the edge DataFrame are missing from vertices DataFrame')
```

However, this does not make much sense, because names_edges are numerical and names_vertices are strings. So I tried to edit this code to change the line featuring len() to

```
    if len(np.setdiff1d(names_edges, names_vertices)) != len(names_vertices):
```

but now I receive a new error:

```
raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")

KeyError: "None of [Float64Index([1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0], dtype='float64')] are in the [index]"
```

I changed the len() line back to the default and will wait for further help to come in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for asking, I added that function and it was a little buggy, so I fixed it two days ago or so. Please try python-igraph from the master branch.

Even in your version, the idea of that vertex names are strings. Cast the first two columns of edges and the first column of vertices to string and even the buggy version should work.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response! That is good to hear. I am still a bit newer to python and I am wondering what you mean specifically by trying from the master branch?

Comment: It's not Python, it's git: https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph. If you don't know how to use git, I'd recommend just cast the columns to strings as indicated above and wait for the next release. Thanks